# Mosaic() changing image scale using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, geemap

I am trying to filter an image collection to one date (2015) and create one image (the collection is made up of multiple tiles). Filtering by date and by bounds is fine, and I have been using .Mosaic() to merge all of the tiles within the bounds to one image, which I can then clip by an AOI.

However, after .Mosaic() has been applied, the scale of the image changes from ~30m to 111319.49079327357m.

Why is this happening and how can it be avoided?

I would like to keep my analysis at its native resolution. I have been doing through GEE map too and get the same result.

Here is a link to a GEE script looking at this https://code.earthengine.google.com/8f3e3a50f73c5c52f28fe09240887fb0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the scale to 30 by using .reproject()

```
    // Get CRS
    print('Projection: ', ee.ImageCollection("NASA/MEASURES/GFCC/TC/v3").first().projection())

   // Reproject
   var statScaleMosaicreproject = mosaicked.reproject('EPSG:32623', null, 30)
   print('Scale in meters after mosaicked after reprojection: ',statScaleMosaicreproject.projection().nominalScale().getInfo());
```